# Binary Search Tree using pointers to pointers problem

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm relatively new to coding in C++. I'm trying to make a BST in C++ and I'm using pointers for this but I can't figure out the error in pointers even after spending hours of time. Basically, the error comes in the if statement, where I'm trying to use recursion to change root when there are children present from parent root.
Here is the code

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    struct node* rightchild;
    int data;
    struct node* leftchild;
};

struct node* newNode(int data){
    struct node* node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*node1).data=data;
    (*node1).leftchild = NULL;
    (*node1).rightchild = NULL;
    return node1;
}

void insertIntoBST(struct node** ptrtoroot, struct node** ptrtotemp){
    if((**ptrtotemp).data <= (**ptrtoroot).data){
        if((**ptrtoroot).leftchild != NULL){
            insertIntoBST((*ptrtoroot).leftchild,(*ptrtotemp));
        }
        else{
           (*ptrtoroot->leftchild) = *ptrtotemp;
        }
    }
     if((**ptrtotemp).data > (**ptrtoroot).data){
        if((**ptrtoroot).rightchild != NULL){
            insertIntoBST((*ptrtoroot->rightchild),(*ptrtotemp));
        }
        else{
           (*ptrtoroot->rightchild) = *ptrtotemp;
        }
    }
    
}

void inorder(struct node* root){
    while(root != NULL){
        cout<<(*root).data;
        inorder((*root).leftchild);
        inorder((*root).rightchild);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct node* root = NULL;
    struct node* temp;
    int dat;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
    cin>>dat;
    temp = newNode(dat);
    if(root == NULL){
        root = temp;
    }
    else{
        insertIntoBST(&root,&temp);
    }
 }
 inorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Error code:

```
bst.cpp:21:40: error: request for member ‘leftchild’ in ‘* ptrtoroot’, which is of pointer type ‘node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)  
21 | insertIntoBST((ptrtoroot).leftchild,(*ptrtotemp));  
   | ^~~~~~~~~ bst.cpp:24:25: error: request for member ‘leftchild’ in ‘ ptrtoroot’, which is of pointer type ‘node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)  
24 | (*ptrtoroot->leftchild) = *ptrtotemp;
```

Comment: Show us the error message you are getting

Comment: bst.cpp:21:40: error: request for member ‘leftchild’ in ‘* ptrtoroot’, which is of pointer type ‘node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   21 |             insertIntoBST((*ptrtoroot).leftchild,(*ptrtotemp));
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~
bst.cpp:24:25: error: request for member ‘leftchild’ in ‘* ptrtoroot’, which is of pointer type ‘node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   24 |            (*ptrtoroot->leftchild) = *ptrtotemp;

Comment: *im relatively new to coding in c++* -- That code is all `C`, with barely any, if any, C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `#include<iostream>` Makes it *technically* `C++`, but I agree with you; this is `C` code. You wouldn't write this in C++ this way.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need the keyword `struct` when declaring function parameters.  This is required in C.  Which language are you programming in?

Comment: Since you are programming in C++, you should put node methods inside the `struct`.  Also, prefer to use `operator new` to `malloc` because `malloc` doesn't call the `struct` constructor.

Comment: In C++, you can pass by reference which eliminates the need to pass by pointer.  Pointers can point to anywhere and are difficult to validate (testing that a pointer points to a valid memory location).  Much safer to pass by reference.

Comment: Your code may be easier to read by using the `->` operator, something like this: `(*ptrtoroot)->data`

Comment: Don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`. Don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new` (or even better; use smart pointers). Don't put `struct` at the start of variable declarations, that's needed in `C`, not in `C++`. Don't use C-style casts (with `()`), use the C++ style casts instead (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` etc).

Comment: thank you all for the information ,  i will take care of all these things in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay by looks of it I think in your function as shown below.

```
void insertIntoBST(struct node** ptrtoroot, struct node** ptrtotemp){
    if((**ptrtotemp).data <= (**ptrtoroot).data){
        if((**ptrtoroot).leftchild != NULL){
            insertIntoBST((*ptrtoroot).leftchild,(*ptrtotemp));
```

ptrtoroot is double pointer i.e pointer to pointer so this makes (*ptrtoroot) a pointer and here

```
(*ptrtoroot).leftchild should be replaced with "->" operator 
like (*ptrtoroot)->leftchild
```

Secondly under recursive calls insertIntoBST function takes double pointer as argument so you need to pass address of pointer here.

i.e Address of a pointer returned by (*ptrtoroot)->leftchild from your node structure.

```
something like &((*ptrtoroot)->leftchild)
```

I have not completely executed your code but this should work.

Same goes for the second parameter (*ptrtotemp).

Comment: thank you so much i completely forgot that leftchild is itself a pointer and i need to pass address of leftchild for this to work , your explanation was on point finally my code is working (https://www.imageupload.net/image/ex8Tc)